# Class / Single Table Inheritance or another method?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

There will be an "Account" which can be a "Customer" or a "Supplier", or both. It has to be one of them at-least.

I am wanting to use Class Table Inheritance but I'm unsure whether I will be able to have an Account that can be both a Customer and a Supplier.

Can anyone confirm?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have to check this in the application to make sure a user is customer and/or supplier

Comment: @Cid OP actually allows to be both of them, but doesn't allow to be none of them. The question is about something else.

Comment: I'd want it so that an account can either be both or be one - not none. Edit: I'm just not sure if Class Table Inheritance would do that?

Comment: @JakubMatczak thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think STI is the right choice for your problem since it's more like a many-to-many relationship.

You're question is a little too broad to give you exact answer. Depending on your need you may have a few options.

For example, if being `Customer`/`Supplier` means to have additional data, it would be better to make them a separate entities with relationship to the `Account`. So in your app, you would recognize if an `Account` is a `Customer` or `Supplier` by checking if appropriate related entity exist. So it you could explain it as

> An `Account` can have `Customer` or `Supplier` profile

o something like this, instead of

> `Account` can be a `Customer` or `Supplier`

Other solution would be to treat it as a simple ACL, where `Account` is a subject, and `Customer` and `Supplier` are roles.

I'ts hard to provide more detailed answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more detail initially. The reason I am thinking of Class Table Inheritance is because Customers and Suppliers will use the same columns in the Accounts table, but also at the same time have additional data in their own tables. For example, the Accounts table will have accountName, accountRef, accountCountry ..etc which both Customers and Suppliers share, but then the Customer table have additional data that a Supplier won't have, e.g. credit_limit; and vice-versa.

Comment: There's a good principle called "composition over inheritance". You should change the way you're think about your OOP code design. You definitely should treat them as separate entities.

Comment: @JetLee I suppose you could have three entities, CustomerAccount, SupplierAccount and CustomerAndSupplierAccount.  But that will probably get very messy very quickly.  If a User is both a supplier and a customer then they should pick one or the other when they login.  Does it really make sense for them to be both at the same time when using your site?

Comment: @Cerad what about resellers? Someone who is the customer of a supplier and the supplier of another customer

Comment: @Cid In that case I'd probably have a ResellersAcount.  But this is all speculation without knowing the actual requirements.